# voiceChannel undefenition

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I started the music part of my discord bot. Now, as I did in my last question, here's the snippet for the Music command only: [Pastebin #1](https://pastebin.com/ZUyxsB1V)

At the line where it says `if (msg.member.voiceConnection === undefined) return msg.channel.sendMessage(wrap(':x: You\'re not in a voice channel.'));`, the console: [Pastebin #2](https://pastebin.com/V6AZ4NU7)

Another undefined error. I'm confused as to what's undefined here. I searched around the discord.js.org documentation to no avail. (The discord.js official discord wasn't much of a help either.) I always get confused with undefined errors.

I also tried using `if (guild.member.voiceConnection)` with the same error.

I just don't see what is undefined, and maybe I haven't had coffee yet, and I'm missing something really obvious, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Undefined means it has no value at all and is thereby not known. You can compare it like with an array of 5 items then you try getting index 7. That's not known thereby **undefined**.

To find the voiceChannel of the user you don't need to use .voiceConnection but you need .voiceChannel. This will be undefined if you are **not** in a voice channel. Otherwise it'll provide you the channel information :)

EDIT: But there is more wrong than only that I see now. You used msg.member but msg is just a string with the content of the message. You'll need the message object from the message event to check on .member.voiceChannel not on the content of the message

Comment: ooOOOOh i see now, I didn't realize any of this before, much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the **methods** you're using are depreciated, so let me just cover those first.

```js
if (msg.member.voiceConnection === undefined) 
     return msg.channel.sendMessage(wrap(':x: You\'re not in a voice channel.'));
```

First of all, `msg.channel.sendMessage` should be `message.channel.send`. Next, `msg.member.voiceConnection` should be `msg.member.voiceChannel`. 
You can check the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voiceChannel).

So after all these changes we have:

```
if (msg.member.voiceChannel === undefined) 
     return msg.channel.send(wrap(':x: You\'re not in a voice channel.'));
```

Comment: I do see what's wrong here, much thanks for the help, and also I see that `msg` is the message content, which doesn't help when getting a voiceChannel. I've fixed it to work, thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem, have fun coding